# Mock jdbcTemplate instantiated by class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I got a class that creates it's own jdbcTemplate using `new jdbcTemplate(dataSource)` and creates its own NamedParameterJdbcTemplate when needed using new `NameParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate)`. How do I use Mockito to make it so that when unit testing the templates are mocked templates that I can control the return value of?

Comment: You're already using Spring, why not inject the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate rather than creating a new instance?

Answer (score 0):

You could create special package level method which would create those objects and then mock them with the usage of `@Spy` feature:

**1)** Create the specialized methods:

```
public class MyClass{

    private Datasource ds;

    public void methodUnderTest(){
         JdbcTemplate template = getTemplateInstance(ds);

         ...
    }

    JdbcTemplate getTemplateInstance(Datasource ds){
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }
}
```

**2)** Spy the class and mock the instance creation methods:

```
public class MyClassTest{

     @Spy
     @InjectMocks
     private MyClass myClassSpy;

     @Mock
     private Datasource dsMock;

     @Mock
     private JdbcTemplate templateMock;

     @Before
     public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     }

     @Test
     public void test(){
          // Arrange
          doReturn(templateMock).when(myClassSpy).getTemplateInstance(dsMock);

          // Act and Assert ...
     }
}
```